# What methods were used to make Christian Bale look so much like Dick Cheney in the film "Vice"?

Tags: method-acting, vice

Its pretty well known the lengths that Christian Bale has gone to in the past to play certain roles including both losing and gaining weight. The primary example I can think of being [The Machinist (2004)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0361862/) in which he ate a diet of a can of tuna and an apple per day in order to lose 63 pounds.

Having just seen the trailer for the upcoming movie [Vice (2018)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6266538/) in which he is set to play Dick Cheney, I have to say that I'm kind of amazed at the transformation of the actor to look like Dick Cheney. I in fact could not tell who it was until the trailer displayed Christian Bale's name on screen.

The other thing that came to my mind was the amazing transformation of Gary Oldman into Churchill for [Darkest Hour (2017)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4555426/?ref_=nv_sr_1) which was largely due to prosthetics as well as, of course, phenomenal acting.

So, I'm left to wonder how much of Bale's transformation into Dick Cheney is due to prosthetics and makeup and how much is due to him going through a similar physical transformation as he's done for previous roles?

Comment: I have no documentary evidence, but they were talking about it on the radio today - he got fat, no CGI.

Comment: Whoever voted to close want to explain how this is a trivia question?

Comment: Woof that felt like a parody trailer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, he gained weight, did specific exercises, shaved his head, and used make-up artists.

> To [shape-shift](https://www.vanityfair.com/hollywood/2018/10/christian-bale-dick-cheney-movie) accordingly, Bale has said that he shaved his
>   head, bleached his eyebrows, and gained 40 pounds. (Co-star Carell
>   also said that Bale did specific exercises to thicken his neck.) This
>   January, Bale waved off any praise for the extreme
>   character-preparation, telling Yahoo that he was just trying to
>   provide “a blank canvas through which these incredible [hair and
>   makeup] artists could create the various ages of Cheney. . . . They
>   would shave my head every day, bleach and pluck eyebrows.”